# How do you cut a regular $n$-simplex in two symmetrical halves?

Tags: linear-algebra, puzzle, simplex

I felt like I had to repost this question because I didn't explain it well enough in the first attempt.

Given a regular $n$-simplex find a way to cut it in half with a plane so that each half looks the same and is mirrored (not point symmetrical). You cannot rotate the halves so that they are symmetrical.

How do you do it for a $n$-simplex in higher dimensions than 3? If we look at the 3-simplex but in 3 dimensions instead of 4, you can only do it by cutting along one edge. Is it the same in 4 dimensions?

I know that the hyperplane we use to cut a simplex always has $n-1$-dimensional volume, so I cannot imagine it in my head.

Also, I'd like to minimize the points that are neither in one half or the other.

Comment: In the title you mention a *regular* simplex, but not in the question body.  Are you only considering regular simplices or not?

Comment: Yes, only regular $n$-simplices.

Answer (score 6):

Choose any face of the $n$-simplex.  That face is an $(n-1)$-simplex; bisect it using an $(n-2)$-plane.  (Assume we already know how to do this... this method is inductive.). Then form the $(n-1)$-plane containing that $(n-2)$-plane and the final point of the simplex.  This plane bisects your original simplex.

Note how this works for the tetrahedron: you bisect a face, with a line segment, and then the plane containing that line segment and the final point cuts the tetrahedron in half.

Comment: You may start even earlier by noting how it works for a planar triangle: you bisect one edge with a point and then the line containing that point and the remaining vertex bisects the triangle.

Comment: So if I go higher from the tetrahedron / 3-simplex to the 4-simplex I need to add a third point to the hyperplane? Does that mean I have to use 3 points or can it be done with less?

Comment: Also, how many hyperplanes are there to do this in $n$-dimensions? A 2-simplex can be divided by 3 lines. A 3-simplex by the number of edges. Is there a simple formula?

Comment: The cut resulting from the method presented is a perpendicular bisector of a line segment connecting any two vertices, that is a hyper- (or hypo-) plane passing through a midpoint of the line segment and normal to that line. It would also pass through all remaining vertices.

Comment: @Dude From my previous comment it follows there is a cut for each pair of vertices. An $n$-dimensional simplex has $n+1$ vertices, so it has ${n+1 \choose 2} =(n+1)n$ such cuts.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Dude Made a mistake, forgot one divisor: ${n+1 \choose 2}$ equals $(n+1)n\color{red}{/2}$.